Ignoring warning emitted by libs in `venv` using `pytest`
I'm using pytest lib for testing and sometimes I get warnings emitted in code in libs imported (all are in /venv directory).
I do not want to turn off warnings that are emitted in code I wrote, but warnings emitted in code of any 3rd party lib are of no use.
How to turn off or hide all warnings that come from code in /venv?
One specific example for my use case can be:
============================================ warnings summary ============================================ 
test_auth.py: 3 warnings
  C:\Users\User\<my project>\security.py:33: DeprecationWarning: datetim
e.datetime.utcnow() is deprecated and scheduled for removal in a future version. Use timezone-aware objects to represent datetimes in UTC: datetime.datetime.now(datetime.UTC).
    expire = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=settings.REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_DAYS)
===
^ this line is in code I wrote, warnings should be turned on.
===

test_auth.py: 2 warnings
  C:\Users\User\<my project>\venv\Lib\site-packages\jose\jwt.py:311: DeprecationWarning: datetime.datetime.utcnow() is deprecated and scheduled for removal in a future version. Use timezone-aware objects to represent datetimes in UTC: datetime.datetime.now(datetime.UTC).
    now = timegm(datetime.utcnow().utctimetuple())
===
^ this line is somewhere in python-jwt lib in /venv, I dont want to see them at all. 
===

I checked these ( 1 2 3 ) Qs, and they either turn off all warnings completely or ignore specific warnings or types of warnings - either is useless in my use case.

perhaps this might help How to suppress a third-party warning using warnings.filterwarnings It is similar to your first link but highlights that your regex pattern might be set to be less specific.
